# Preventing img from loading in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a div with an image:

```
<div ng-if="showIt">
    <img src="{{filepath}}/{{filename}}">
    <!-- ... and a bunch other other elements -->
</div>
```

The thing is `{{filepath}}` and `{{filename}}` will be null if `showIt` is false.

However, I always see a 404 error in my console because I think Angularjs is rendering the whole DOM, and then removing the bits where `ng-if` evaluates to false. This means the browser will always request the non-existent images even when `showIt` is false.

Is there a way prevent the DOM from creating that entire div block, so that the non-existent images will never be requested by the browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ng-src:

```
<img ng-src="{{filepath}}/{{filename}}">
```

The 404 errors you see aren't caused by ng-if. They're caused by the fact that the browser tries to load the image before the angular expression is evaluated by Angular. `ng-src` only adds the `src` attribute to the image once the expression is evaluated, avoiding HTTP requests to `{{filepath}}/{{filename}}`.